# How many way i can smooth my Mesh?

Tags: mesh, vertices, topology

This is my mesh

[image]

[image]

I have already smooth it but i would like to create a smoother surface in several points like these (reduce these angles)

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this goal without moving eache vertex from myself? I know that i can smooth face/edge when i export it in fbx but isn't enought; are there other ways?

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several tools you can use to smooth out edge loops.

1. Use the Smooth Vertex tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, Smooth Vertex).
2. Use the Relax tool (<kbd>W</kbd>, Relax).
3. Use the Curve and/or Relax tools from the LoopTools addon that comes
   with Blender.
4. Use proportional editing (<kbd>O</kbd>).
5. Use a Smooth or Laplacian Smooth modifier.
6. Use a Subdivision Surface modifier (this will add new geometry to the mesh).

Comment: I can't find Relax tool you mentioned in the second point in the Specials menù. Does it need an add-on?

Comment: Ah yes, go to User Preferences, Addons, "Mesh: Relax". But I prefer the LoopTools Relax anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the bevel modifier with an angle threshold.

This will bevel all angles above the angle you choose.

Plus you can control how big of a bevel and how smooth

Properties editor->modifiers->Generate->Bevel

Limit method: angle

https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/bevel.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a way. It will also help with the weird shading. Select your object, go to the *Object modifiers* tab in the *Properties panel*, and select *Subdivision surface.* The higher the *Render:* value, the smoother the surface; 2 or 3 should do it for you. The *View:* value determines the amount of subdivisions shown in the *3D Viewport*; 1 should do. You will not need to change the other settings.